# Creating new data frame from two uneven sized data frames

Tags: python, pandas

So first I took 5 samples(df2) from a data frame(df1) containing 600 rows. Now I want all those entries of those 5 samples that I have taken extracted into new data frame(df3).

df1 has a column 'village' from which I sampled 5 different villages into df2 (there are 70 villages total and 600 entries of these villages)

df2 sampled villages are 5 therefore df3 should contain all 5 villages data from df1.

So i have to do it by using groupby, lambda, loc

So i have to do it by using groupby, lambda, loc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

z = df2.tolist()

vdf = df1[df1['Village'].isin(z)]

print(vdf)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).